# c++ method start thread with method

Tags: c++, multithreading, methods

I have seen that the following syntax is correct (or so I think), but vscode with microsoft's extension for c / c ++ underlines the "&" before "A::ToThread" (in A.cpp file) in red and says:

> no instance of the constructor "std :: __ 1 :: thread :: thread"
> matches the argument list

The program "apparently" works, but I think something is not right.

The code:

> A.h

```
class A{
public:
    void CreateThread();
    void ToThread(std::string s);
};
```

> A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
void A::CreateThread(){
    std::thread th(&A::ToThread, this, "something");
    th.detach();
}
void A::ToThread(std::string s){
    while(1){
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

> main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
int main(){
    A a;
    a.CreateThread();
    while(1){}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a vs code highlighter bug.  Your code is valid and does compile: https://godbolt.org/z/d6784o1GG

Comment: @NathanOliver Is there a way to quit the bug, or will I have to see the alert constantly?

Comment: Not sure about that.  I don't use VS code.

Comment: So it would be better to use the classic visual studio (the purple one) for c ++?

Comment: Meh.  I prefer to use MSVS but that's just because I love the debugger.  Even it's highlighter has bugs.

Comment: "IntelliSense" has always been imperfect.  It's hard to say whether you will get better results from using a different version of IntelliSense.

Comment: I do not use MS tools, but as far as I know, vscode just runs compiler in the background thread and collects it's diagnostic. It is strange that such an error is produced. Perhaps there are ways to adjust how this compiler is run.

Comment: Think of Intellisence, CODAN, and similar tools as a compiler that trades accuracy for speed so that it's usable in real-time checking. When it raises an error that you don't agree with, check it with a real compile and see what the compiler thinks.

Comment: If you switch to a lambda, it might remove the error.  Try using `std::thread th([this](){ ToThread("something"); });`

Comment: Another alternative: `std::thread th(std::bind(&A::ToThread, this, "something"));`